# Change text color in navigation bar Android Studio with getSupportActionBar()

Tags: android, navbar, textcolor

is there an option to programatically change the navigation bar text color in Android Studio? I have changed the background color successfully in one line but I cannot change the text color. Sorry, very beginning at Android Studio :)

here's how I changed the background color:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#C0FA94")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code to set color and text to Action bar :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>ActionBar title </font>"));
```

color mod is RGB .